# Disappeared table header row after using "stacked" property

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Some days ago, on ALL of my `<b-table>` which were using `stacked="md"` property, the table headers row disappeared. If I remove this property, headers row becomes visible, but I needed this property for stacking tables on low resolution or mobile displays.

Header row was visible before and I don't understand why it's disappearing now. When I add this prop to table on official bootstrap-vue site it disappears there too. Maybe it was updated and it's suppose to has other behavior?

Example:
https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/19/50fe617509fccfb770a19a58542c8e1b-full.jpg

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: This is an issue with RC.28, it has been fixed for the next release which will be 2.0.0.
For now I'd suggest going back to RC.27

Comment: @Hiws where did you get that info? I can't find an official response to this bug.

Comment: @DanielMarín It was mentioned on the official discord by one of the main contributors.

Comment: It is mentioned in a pinned issue at the github repo: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues (https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3886)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and after I did some tests I assume it was a bug in v2.0.0-rc.28. Thanks to @Hiws comment, I was able to find the "official" report of the bug in a discord channel and then, the actual commit where this bug is fixed:

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/commit/2302b31d63290abcf72b52d3ddb5d6a6767ec356

So, **it is officially a bug and it will be fixed in next version** (probably 2.0.0 stable).